# Performance issue in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a `ngRepeat` block that iterates over an array of objects that draws row accordingly.

One of the properties of the object is a string that requires some transformation before displayed.

Performancewise, is it right to run the function everytime Angular runs its loop?

```
   <div ng-repeat="a in arr">{{ strTransform(a.name) }}</div>
```

Comment: `{{:: strTransform(a.name) }}` in angular 1.3+ for run once that evaluate to non-undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it is OK, performance-wise and everything, unless:

1. your transformation function itself is way too expensive, in which case you're doomed, or:
2. you got a humongous amount of elements to process, in which case you're doomed with the rendering time anyway.

--

As a side note, I'd like to add that you might wanna use an [Angular **filter** (link)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for these kinds of operations :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I considered using the filter - is there a difference between direct function like I suggested to filter (the transformation will be used only in this part of the app)

Comment: Nope, if you're not planning on reusing this transformation, having it like this is all right. although as you guessed, it'd be much more recommended to use a filter otherwise, for maintenance and readability purposes :)

Comment: +1 for recommending filters, even if it's not going to be used anywhere else, it helps to keep controllers focused on what controllers are for.

Comment: Thanks, moving it to filters :)